# Alternative to multiple greps

Tags: bash, grep

I am reading a list of outputs for pipewire in a shell script and looking for a specific entry. I don't know the exact name but I know the words that are in it. To find it I am using multiple greps for each word I know will be in the entry

`pw-cli list-objects | grep node.name | grep output | grep pci | grep analog`

Is there an alternative to doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what the sample input would be and your expected output.  As written your code looks for lines that contain **all** of those strings in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use awk for this:

```
pw-cli list-objects | awk '/node\.name/ && /output/ && /pci/ && /analog/'
```

Or maybe perl if I needed perl's regex syntax, or other perl language features or library modules (neither of which are actually needed for this example):

```
pw-cli list-objects | 
  perl -n -e 'print if (/node\.name/ && /output/ && /pci/ && /analog/)'
```

There are two main benefits in using awk or perl for this:

1. it will match input lines regardless of the order of words in the input.  i.e. a regex like `node\.name.*output.*pci.*analog` will match only if those words are in the input line in **exactly** that order.  The awk or perl one-liners above will match if ALL four words are present anywhere in the input line, in any order - this is equivalent to the way you've chained multiple `grep`s together in the pipeline.

   You *could* use extended regexps with alternations (`|`) for every placement variation, but with four words, you'd need 16 alternate versions to match every possible arrangement, so that's kind of impractical - `(a.*b.*c.*d)|(a.*c.*b.*d)|(a.*b.*d.*c)|.........`
2. You can use any combination of `&&` (AND), `||` (OR), `!` (negation), and parentheses to construct an arbitrarily complex boolean conditional.  You can also combine with any other awk or perl syntax that returns a true or false result (e.g. calculations & comparisons based on fields within the input line).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using "regular expressions". Read `man grep`.

```
# if they're on the same linr
pw-cli | grep 'node\.name.*output.*pci.*analog'
# or if they're not
pw-cli | grep 'node\.name|output<pci|analog'
```

Comment: your first command defines them to be in that specific order - which might not be the case.